# JavaFX Windows 10 native bundle deployment - Exception Access Violation

Tags: java, windows, javafx, deployment, self-contained

I'm working on a JavaFX 8 application for communication to a physical device via Windows virtual Com-Port.

- Windows 7/10 64Bit
- IDE Eclipse Mars
- Ant
- InnoSetup 5.5.6
- jdk 1.8.0_121
- jssc 2.7.0  - for serial port communication

I'm building the native installer with Ant and InnoSetup. After installation the application can be launched via the native launcher (App.exe) on Windows 7 and 10.
On Windows 7 I can open the Com-Port and the application works perfectly.
As soon as I try to open the Com-Port on Windows 10, the jvm crashes with the following message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ec4b5bb, pid=1632, tid=0x0000000000001898
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jSSC-2.7_x86_64.dll+0xb5bb]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Opening the virtual Com-Port on Windows 10 works when the application is lauched by double clicking the App.jar instead of the App.exe.
Both, the native launcher (App.exe) and the jar (App.jar) use the system jre.

What can I do to make the application (launched by App.exe) run on both platforms?

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried running the `.exe` as `Administrator`?

Comment: I tried to run the .exe as Administrator by right click -> Run as Administrator and via command line with Admin privileges. Both did not do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The crash seems to be occured in native code "C  [jSSC-2.7_x86_64.dll+0xb5bb]" inside jSSC-2.7_x86_64.dll file it may be due to the fact that how api's are being called to this library, check your program. 
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION indicate that your code tried to access memory location for which it doesn't have read permission (0xc0000005)

As the program works fine on windows 7,, check the compatible serial port driver for windows 10. The crash could be due to driver mismatch

Comment: When I launch the program by double-clicking the .jar instead of the .exe on windows 10, it works fine. So I guess the serial port driver is doing ok. There seem to be different access rights when the app is launched by ".exe". Installing and running as administrator and disabling the UAC did not solve the problem.